# Change element name when serializing class

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I'm facing a minor issue, and have tried a few solutions recommended here, but not working for me for some reason.

One of my elements is retaining the "_" when serialized.  Any thoughts on what I may be missing?

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization


Public Class AddressBook
    Private _AddressEntries As New List(Of AddressBookEntry)
    Public _AddressGroups As New List(Of AddressBookGroup)

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="AddressEntries")> _
    Public Property AddressEntries As List(Of AddressBookEntry)
        Get
            Return _AddressEntries
        End Get

        Set(value As List(Of AddressBookEntry))
            _AddressEntries = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="AddressGroups")> _
    Public Property AddressGroups As List(Of AddressBookGroup)
        Get
             Return _AddressGroups
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of AddressBookGroup))
            _AddressGroups = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class AddressBookEntry
    Private _Country As String
    Private _AddressGroup As AddressBookGroup
    Private _IPAddress As String
    Private _Name As String
    Private _StoreNumber As String

    Public Property Country As String
        Get
            Return _Country
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Country = value.ToString.ToUpper
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property AddressGroup As AddressBookGroup
        Get
            Return _AddressGroup
        End Get
        Set(value As AddressBookGroup)
            _AddressGroup = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IPAddress As String
        Get
            Return _IPAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _IPAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property StoreNumber As String
        Get
            Return _StoreNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _StoreNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(AddressGroup As AddressBookGroup,
               IPAddress As String,
               Name As String,
               StoreNumber As String)
        Me._AddressGroup = AddressGroup
        Me._IPAddress = IPAddress
        Me._Name = Name
        Me._StoreNumber = StoreNumber
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class AddressBookGroup
    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(GroupName As String)
         Me._Name = GroupName
    End Sub
End Class
```

The output looks like below, not the '_' in the AddressGroups element?

```
     <AddressBook xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <_AddressGroups>
        <AddressBookGroup>
            <Name>None</Name> 
        </AddressBookGroup>
    </_AddressGroups>
     <AddressEntries>
        <AddressGroup>
            <Name>None</Name> 
        </AddressGroup>
        <IPAddress>a.b.c.d</IPAddress> 
        <Name>MyName</Name> 
        <StoreNumber>MyNumber</StoreNumber> 
    </AddressEntries>
    <AddressGroups>
        <Name>None</Name> 
    </AddressGroups>
</AddressBook>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a Public declaration rather than Private.